# Javascript not recognized jinja sintax

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to use jinja with javascript, but the jinja sintax it's not working as expected.

I'm using this tutorial as reference -> https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/creating-charts-with-chart-js-in-a-flask-application/, but when I run the code this error is shown:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%'**

Javascript code:

```
var chartData = {
  labels : [{% for item in labels %}
             "{{item}}",
            {% endfor %}],
  datasets : [{
      label: '{{ legend }}',
      data : [{% for item in values %}
                "{{item}}",
              {% endfor %}],
  }]
}
```

Python code:

```
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"],  values = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 7, 8], legend = 'Monthly Data')
```

In the html, i'm importing the js of this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/test-chart.js"></script>
```

And using the graph normally

```
<canvas id="myChart" class="chart-canvas"></canvas>,
```

I already tried to do:

```
var labels = {{ labels|safe }}
```

And use labels = labels, but didn't work too :/ Error in the {{}} sintax.

Comment: It didn`t works too. Using of this way, the graph is shown with {% for item in labels %}{{item}},{% endfor %} as string, instead of get the value from array.

Answer (score 0):

You need add all array data to dictionary `context`.

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    labels = ["January", "February", "March",
              "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"]
    values = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 7, 8]
    legend='Monthly Data'
    
    context = {
        'labels': labels,
        'values': values,
        'legend': legend,
    }

    return render_template("index.html", context=context)
```

And in your script, we need convert `python dictionary` to `javascript object` with `JSON.parse`:

```
<script>
        var context = JSON.parse('{{ context | tojson }}');
        
        var chartData = {
            labels: context.labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: context.legend,
                data: context.values,
            }]
        }

        console.log(chartData);
</script>
```

Here is result:

[image]

Note: You can also get data in `labels`.
Example like: `console.log(context.labels[2]);`.

And it's will return result: [image]